# Why didn't my buttons respond to my action listener

Tags: java, swing

I am a noob and this is my first question on this website. I was working on my rhythm game in java, but I don't know why this didn't click.

My button class

```
public class Button extends JButton implements ActionListener  {
private int x, y;
private ImageIcon icon;
public JButton button;

public Button(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    icon = new ImageIcon("Betterbutton.png");
    button = new JButton();
    button.setIcon(icon);
    button.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    
    
    
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==button) {
System.out.println("Clicked");
}
}

public void draw(Graphics g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(icon.getImage(), x, y, button.getWidth(), button.getHeight(), button);
}
```

My game class

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener,     MouseMotionListener,  ActionListener  {
private BufferedImage back;
private int key;

private Button[] buttons;

public Game() {
    new Thread(this).start();


    // Create an array of MyButton objects
    buttons = new Button[2];
    buttons[0] = new Button( 100, 500);
    buttons[1] = new Button( 500, 500);
    
    for (Button button : buttons) {
        button.button.addActionListener(this);
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5);
            repaint();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D twoDgraph = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (back == null)
        back = (BufferedImage) ((createImage(getWidth(), getHeight())));

    Graphics g2d = back.createGraphics();

    g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

    g2d.setFont(new Font("Broadway", Font.BOLD, 50));

    // Draw all the buttons
    for (Button button : buttons) {
        button.draw(g2d);
    }

    twoDgraph.drawImage(back, null, 0, 0);
}




@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (Button button : buttons) {
        if (button.getBounds().contains(e.getPoint())) {
            System.out.println("Button clicked");
            
        }
    }
   
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (Button button : buttons) {
        if (e.getSource() == button.button) {
            System.out.println("Button clicked!");
            // Do something when a button is clicked
        }
    }
}
```

*I deleted a few lines of unimportant code to make this post shorter, etc, the import and the other mouselistener

I tried adding a mouselistener and actionlistener in both class, but the problem might be that I am drawing the pictures wrong.

Comment: `public class Button extends JButton` is a bad place to start

Comment: `button = new JButton();` is never displayed in any context which would be useful, so the user can't click it so it's `ActionListener` will never be triggered

Comment: Swing is NOT thread safe, your `Thread` is dangerous and you should consider using a Swing `Timer` instead.  Swing is double buffered by default, so you "backing buffer" implementation is pointless and you should be overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint` anyway.

Comment: I could reimplement your entire logic by simply making use of the standard Swing library, so I'm not seeing the point of the custom painting workflow or "thread"

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer to your question is, because that's not how it works.

Swing is NOT thread safe, you should not be updating the UI, or any state the UI relies on, from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

`public class Button extends JButton implements ActionListener  {` is pointless, you're not adding any new functionality to the class and instead are creating ANOTHER instance of `JButton` inside it, which is never displayed in any usable context, so the user will never be able to interact with it.

Since `JButton` already supports displaying `Icon`s, it seems otherwise pointless.

This throws your entire "custom paint" process into question, why would you actually need it, it's not adding anything that wouldn't otherwise be achieved more efficiently and with a lot of less effort on your part.

I would recommend spending some time looking at [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Also, don't think you're smarter then the inbuilt layout system, seriously as someone whose built a few custom layouts in the past, it's complicated!  Make use of the available libraries and save yourself a lot of trouble.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

The following example will, basically, do exactly what you seem to be wanting to do, with a lot less effort...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Did click " + e.getActionCommand());
                }
            };
            for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/RainbowHand.png"))));
                btn.setActionCommand("Button" + index);
                btn.addActionListener(actionListener);
                add(btn);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I would also suggest looking at:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)